# Django module filtering on template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I apologize for my English.
I'm a fresh face in Django, doing my first app, learning the same time.
There have been some pumps on the road, but so far it has been a enjoiable ride.

The app I'm doing is going to be a questionnaire.
The idea is, that you can add new questions under admin panel, and then on the website visitors can answer the questions for feed back.

I would like to make it from scratch for learning purposes.

I have made a model that consist of two parts: Question tag and Question itself.
I'm wonder how could I prevent creating same Question tag twice in the template. All the questions with the same tag name should show under one Question tag, not duplicate itself.

I will show what I mean:
First the code:

## model.py

```
class QuestionTag (models.Model):
  tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=55)
  tag_description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
      return u'%s %s' % (self.tag_name, self.tag_description)

class Question (models.Model):
  QUEST_GROUP_NAME = (
      (1, 'Group1'),
      (2, 'Group2'),
  )
  question_group = models.IntegerField(max_length=3, choices=QUEST_GROUP_NAME, blank=False, default=1)
  question_tag = models.ForeignKey('QuestionTag')
  question_box = models.TextField()

  class Meta:
      ordering = ['-question_tag']
```

## view.py

```
class QuestionView(ListView, FormView):

    def get(self, request, person_id=1):

        if not person_id:
            return render(request, '404.html')

        try:
            personbyid = Person.objects.get(pk=person_id)
            questions = Question.objects.filter(question_group=1).order_by('question_tag')

        except Person.DoesNotExist:
            return render(request, '404.html')

        return render_to_response('questions.html',
                {'personbyid ': inetrviewerid ,'Question_group1': questions })
```

## and the template:

```
<form id='formID' action='' method='post' autocomplete="off">{% csrf_token %}

        {% for question in Question_group1 %}
          <div class='question_header'>
             <p class='question_tag'>.{{question.question_tag.tag_name}}</p>
             <p class='question_tag_descript'>({{question.question_tag.tag_description}})</p>
          </div>
      <label class="question_quest">{{question.question_box}}</label>
      <textarea name="answer" placeholder="Some text about the question!" rows="3"></textarea>
    {% endfor %}

 </form>
```

---

### What I have so far is:

-question tag (description)

---Question one?

---textarea

-question tag (description)

---Question two?

---textarea

---

### How could I make the questions appear like that:

-question tag (description)

---Question one?

---textarea

---Question two?

---textarea

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`ifchanged`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) template tag:

```
{% for question in Question_group1 %}
    {% ifchanged question.question_tag %}
      <div class='question_header'>
         <p class='question_tag'>.{{question.question_tag.tag_name}}</p>
         <p class='question_tag_descript'>({{question.question_tag.tag_description}})</p>
      </div>
    {% endifchanged %}
  <label class="question_quest">{{question.question_box}}</label>
  <textarea name="answer" placeholder="Some text about the question!" rows="3"></textarea>
{% endfor %}
```

Now the contents of the ifchanged block will only be output when the question_tag changes.

Comment: Thanks! It works like needed! Django is amazing, one word here and problem solved. Will go and have deeper look in to template tags.
:D